# Interview Solution - Trimming a Gap Buffer

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, buffer

An interview question I encountered involves the implementation of the [Gap Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer) data structure.  In particular, I'm talking about a data structure that is essentially a LinkedList where each Node is a (fairly small) char array.  This is ideal for text editing because you can insert more characters at any point, allocating new arrays if there is no room where you are looking.

Implementing the Gap Buffer itself is no big deal since it looks exactly like a LinkedList, and implementing methods like `Add` and `Remove` are algorithmically straightforward.  Simply insert the new character in the node corresponding to the position if there is room, allocating a new node if more room is needed.

The most difficult question was an efficient implementation of a `Trim` method with the postcondition that when `Trim` is run, all the non-whitespace elements in the Gap Buffer will be "compacted" towards the beginning, that is, all the elements move as far forward as they can and spaces are trimmed out.

The naive method would be to simply iterate through every array element one by one, moving it to the next free space until all the elements have been iterated, and then deleting all the empty nodes at the end of the list.  However, this is less than ideal:

If during iteration we approach an array that is empty, we should immediately remove that array from the list, thus joining the 2 arrays around it.  On the other hand, if we approach an array that is completely full, we should skip over the array since it is already compacted.

Are these two cases the only cases we need to consider when it comes to efficiency?  Are there any other potential improvements?  And what would the fully efficient `Trim` look like algorithmically?

Comment: So, gap buffer is list of small arrays. Can we create new arrays during trimming?

Comment: I'm very confused by this question, possibly because if a misuse of terminology. Gap buffers are _not_ linked lists; they don't even have much in common with linked lists. A gap buffer is an array where all the free space is kept contiguously somewhere in the middle (at the current "cursor" location).  There's no need for a compaction operation.  Some editors use linked lists of gap buffers. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the data structure achieved when many gap buffers are linked together as nodes.  Thus when inserting at any position in the buffer, one can either insert a character into an array position, or, if the array at that position is full, allocate another node in order to provide more space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One improvement would be to detect that the array is empty after we trimmed it. If it's empty then just delete it, instead of copying next array into it.